# How to map one property to multiple property in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

How can I map one property to 2 properties in hibernate ?
Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class ModelAuthor extends Model {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorList", 
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ModelConceptualBook> conceptualBookList;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ConceptualBook")
public class ModelConceptualBook extends Model {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "ConceptualBook_Author", 
               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "conceptualBookId")}, 
               inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authorId")})
    private Set<ModelAuthor> authorList;

    private Set<ModelAuthor> translatorList;
}
```

Now I want to have anaother table `ConceptualBook_Author` for mapping `translatorList` from `ModelConceptualBook` to `conceptualBookList` of `ModelAuthor` like `authorList`.
How can I achieve this functionality?
Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply using other table - for example `ConceptualBook_Translator`.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ConceptualBook_Translator", 
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "conceptualBookId")}, 
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authorId")})
private Set<ModelAuthor> translatorList;
```

And on the other side relationship is as follows:

```
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "translatorList", 
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ModelConceptualBook> booksTranslated;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but what can I write instead of "@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)" for "conceptualBookList" in "ModelAuthor" class?

Comment: Added to answer. It is not instead of, but as an addition to existing. These are two different relationships between same types, role:translator and role:author. If it is needed additional method that combines both sets to one and returns it can of course be added.